# Tab content shows then disappears AJAX Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

The tab content shows when clicked but then it disappears. This is for a chat module I've been working on. I am using codeigniter for my backend. Thank you for all your help!

Here is my JS:

```
function tabFunction(clickedid){
  $.ajax({
    url: base_url + "Admin/get_message_per_customer",
    data: {message: clickedid},
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
       $('#v-pills-tabContent').html(data);
    }
    });
 }
```

Here is my Controller(when you clicked the tab it should display the messages particular with the name you clicked):

```
public function get_customer_messages(){
        $this->load->model('Crud_model');
        $data = $this->Crud_model->chat_admin_customer();
            foreach ($data as $row): 
                if($row->chat_exists == 1)
                {
                    echo "<a class='nav-link' id='";
                    echo $row->customer_id;
                    echo "'onclick='tabFunction(this.id)' data-toggle='pill' href='#v-pills-home' role='tab' aria-controls='v-pills-home' aria-selected='true'";
                    echo "data-id=";
                    echo $row->customer_id;
                    echo ">";
                    echo $row->first_name;
                    echo "&nbsp";
                    echo $row->last_name;
                    echo "</a> <br>"; 
                }
            endforeach;
        die;
    } 
public function get_message_per_customer(){
    $customer_id = $this->input->get('message');
    $this->load->model('Crud_model');
    $data = $this->Crud_model->chat_customer($customer_id);

    echo "<div class='tab-pane fade show' id='v-pills-home' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='v-pills-home-tab'>";
        foreach ($data as $row): 
        if($row->customer_id == NULL && $row->admin_id == 0){
            echo "";
        }elseif($row->customer_id != NULL && $row->admin_id == 0 ){

            $message = $row->message;
            echo "<div class='answer left'>
                    <div class='avatar'>
                    </div>
                    <div class='name'>"; 
            echo "</div>";
                print_r($message);
            echo "</div>";
        }
        if($row->admin_id == 0){
            echo "";
        }
        elseif($row->admin_id == 1){
            echo "<div class='answer right'>
                <div class='avatar'>
                    <img src=".base_url("assets/img/person.png")." alt='User name'>
                </div>
                <div class='name'>Gomoto(Customer Service)</div>";
            $message_admin = $row->message;
            print_r($message_admin);
            echo "</div>";
        }
        endforeach;
        echo "</div>";

}
```

Comment: How are you calling `tabFunction`? Is it setup on a button that is part of a form? If so did you make sure it isn't submitting the form and therefore reloading the page?

Comment: @PatrickEvans I set it up on a button it like this:                                                                           
                    echo "<a class='nav-link' id='";
                    echo $row->customer_id;
                    echo "'onclick='tabFunction(this.id)' data-toggle='pill' href='#v-pills-home' role='tab' aria-controls='v-pills-home' aria-selected='true'";
                    echo "data-id=";
                    echo $row->customer_id;
                    echo ">";